# using two variables in a bash find and replace

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to automate some patching steps and I have written a script to back up the file and then replace the path in the file in all spots, upon testing backing up the files was ok but the find and replace even though it states successful didn't work, I am trying to use said but I am not married to that so if there is a cleaner way I am not opposed, please see my code example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

nodemanager="/u01/app/oracle/admin/domain/mserver/ADF_INT/nodemanager/"
bindirectory="/u01/app/oracle/admin/domain/mserver/ADF_INT/bin/"
ouilocation="/u01/app/oracle/product/fmw/middleware12c/oui/bin/"

date=$(date +"%d-%m-%y")
echo $date
read -p "Please enter the current jdk path: " oldjdk
read -p "Please enter the new jdk path: " newjdk

echo "Backing up an uploading files to remote server...."

cd $nodemanager || exit
cp nodemanager.properties nodemanager_$date.bkp
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; # Again checking if the last operation was successful if not shall exit the 
script
then
    echo -e "nodemanager.properties backup failed"
    echo -e "Terminating script"
    exit 0
fi
sed -i -e 's/${$oldjdk/$newjdk}/g' nodemanager.properties
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; # Again checking if the last operation was successful if not shall exit the 
script
then
    echo -e "find and replace failed for nodemanager.properties"
    echo -e "Terminating script"
    exit 0
fi

echo -e "nodemanager.properties operations completed successfully\n"
```

Thanks
JJ

Answer (score 1):

To save you some trouble on this I figured it out the / is not part of sed it can be any delimiter that is not clashing with the path so I used this:

```
sed -i "s+$oldjdk+$newjdk+g" file
```

Thanks
JJ